# How to loop through arrays in PHP to display the results

Tags: php

I have a query which retrives two colums of multiple rows from the db.I want it to display this in a table using php,I have to use two dimensional arrays i guess.Please help on how shall i proceed.

```
while($row=mysql_fetchrow_array($qry))
{
Please guide how to store the columns in the array[][]


}


[Please guide on how to display the result in the display page]
foreach(   )
{
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the best place to learn php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793134/what-is-the-best-place-to-learn-php)

Comment: a small example in my previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140714/separating-logic-style-in-php-properly/3140805#3140805 a real life example, unlike ones posted below

Comment: There is examples for this in the PHP Manual: http://de3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// store the columns in the array[][]:
$res = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $res[] = $row;
}

// display the result in the display page
echo "<table>\n";
foreach($res as $row) {
   echo "<tr>\n";
   foreach ($row as $fld) {
      echo "<td>$fld</td>\n";
   }
   echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```

Comment: Can i get a solution without using MSql_NUM,with two Dimensional arrays

Comment: user475484: $res IS a two-dimensional array.