# php mysql multiple result

Tags: php, mysql

My php code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id IN (1,3)");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo $row['name'];
    }
```

It returns as last result set, which is from `user_id = 3` and does not include the result of `user_id = 1` but when i `print_r($row)` all the result is there, is there anything amiss?

Thanks

Comment: -1 , please stop using the ancient `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: several examples of looping exist on stack: here's one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931219/how-to-loop-through-arrays-in-php-to-display-the-results

Comment: Does user_id=1 actually have a name set?  Are you sure its not printing an empty string.

Comment: @tereško - Many would not consider that a valid reason for a downvote.

Comment: @tereško Allow me to politely disagree. mysql_ functions are still widely used, and as far as I know, most of them are not even close to being deprecated. Not only is your downvote absurd, considering the approach is valid, you are giving misleading information. I had to +1 this. Happy new year to you and your loved ones, cheers.

Comment: @stefgosselin http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799

Comment: echo $row['user_id'].':'.$row['name'];
im affraid your user_id: 1 has empty name as Toby mentioned above

Comment: @Maerlyn Yes, I agree with that post, it seems to imply we should gently educate users to prefer the newer extensions. Could not find the part that says to bash them down for using mysql_ and leave them hanging without any mention of proper alternatives. Also, could not find anything saying it is plain wrong to use mysql_. I doubt mysql_ is going out of core anytime soon. Cheers!

Comment: @stefgosselin I agree that they should be educated rather than bashed. Just wanted to show that there's official planning to deprecate ext/mysql in the near future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access elements of array by attribute names use this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row["id"], $row["name"]);
}
```

else just use numeric instead of associative keys

as

```
echo $row[0]
```

Comment: Note you can also use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead.