# Prevent user to use back button with warning or disable any insert

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a form in `page1.php` which directs to `page2.php` from where the data from the form in `page1.php` is inserted into database. after successful insertion, `page2.php` displays a message and gives link to go  to a third page.

The problem is when the user after the insertion hits the back button of the browser and clicks the form submit button, insertion is made again.

Is there any way so that after one insertion when the back button is pressed a message will be displayed showing that visiting the back-button is not allowed? Or in  case it is allowed no insertion will take place on clicking the form submit button?

EDITED LATER  TO ADD THIS PART:

okk let me tell in details. it is about an admin back end. the admin gives description text input for different products. He gives the input from page1.php and message is shown on page2.php that the description has been inserted into db. then there is another form below the message. It just asks whether the admin wishes to do  more with description text. If yes, then clicking on the form submit button , he is taken to a page from where across some page(s) he is again taken to page1.php ( this time for another product), from there to page2.php and so on.  btw i could use a normal page link instead of the form button link below the message on page2.php

The problem is, while  the admin is on page2.php and hits the back button , he goes back to page1.php and from there if he hits on the form submit button, the data is inserted for the second time in a new row.

u may suggest to use 'IGNORE' with 'INSERT' command, but there are other columns in the row which may not get matched with those of  another column while the description columns(admin inserts text data for this column ) may get matched.

1)Is ignore applicable in this case?

2)What should be the solution if duplicate entry is allowed for the database of the site?

thanks

hope it makes the whole thing clear.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of giving link to a third page, redirect to the very same URI
this is quite handy method called [POST/Redirect/GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get):
here is a concise example of it:

```
<?php  
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {  

  $err = array();
  //performing all validations and raising corresponding errors
  if (empty($_POST['name'])) $err[] = "Username field is required";  
  if (empty($_POST['text'])) $err[] = "Comments field is required";  

  if (!$err) {  
    //if no errors - saving data and redirect
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit;
  }  else {
    // all field values should be escaped according to HTML standard
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
      $form[$key] = htmlspecialchars($val);
    }
  }
} else {
  $form['name'] = $form['comments'] = '';  
}
include 'form.tpl.php';
?>
```

Here you can see another example, concise yet powerful: 
[Separating Logic/Style in PHP properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140714/separating-logic-style-in-php-properly/3140805#3140805)
it's complete solution to display, add and edit database contents, exactly for admin purpose.

Comment: I was so happy when I discovered the "header" function.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, i am talking about an item insertion. message is  showon on page2.php. on the same page a form submit button is there asking the user whether s/he is interested to make another item insertion. hope i have made it clear to u. i think u need to change ur code. btw "include 'form.tpl.php';" what and how to do with a .tpl.php file ?

Comment: @sof_user it's all depends on the scenario. As you said no word on it, it's impossible to answer certainly. You could use SESSION to prevent this for example, but not for every case

Comment: @sof nope, nothing is clear here. If you want particular answer, you have to ask particular question: what is this form, what is this data, who is that user, is he anonymous or not and what prevents him from entering your site again and filling form from scratch.

Comment: @sof POST/Redirect/GET is the EXACT solution for this. if you use it, an admin will always face EMPTY form, unable to submit a duplicate. Just make it all on one page like it suggested in my code

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, please tell me in details about form.tpl.php in ur code . why is the extension .tpl?

Comment: @sof it's not .tpl, it's .php file. A regular php file contains HTML form. you can see an example following link added in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should not display your message on `page2.php`.

Instead :

- `page2.php` should deal with the data
- when the data has been saved, `page2.php` should redirect to `confirmation.php`
- And it's only `confirmation.php` which would display the message.

For more informations, take a look at the [**Post/Redirect/Get**](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

**Edit after the comment :** but note that, in any case, you will never be able to prevent the user from re-submitting a form, if he really wants to...

The only solution you'll have is, when a form is submitted, to check in your database if the currently submitted data already exists -- and if it does, refuse to insert it again.

Of course, if the suer changes even a single letter in his input, it won't be the same data anymore...

Comment: and what if the user hits back button twice from conformation.php?

Comment: duplicate entry allowed... what to do now?