# PHP Serverside validation (calling a different page)

Tags: php, validation

What is the proper way to validate a form in PHP in server side?  There are tons of examples on the web where the action of the form is itself, but what if the action of my form is another .php file?

For example I have a form element on page1.php.  The action of this form is page2.php.  I know how to validate this in client side, but how would you put a server side validation on this form?

Comment: Could you please give more information? Basically you can access the POST- and GET-varaibles in the target page. `$_POST['input_name'] /* or */ $_GET['input_name']` and the these values in your function.

Comment: Not sure there's much more I can say.  Check out my response to the other poster's answer.  I put some more info there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent user to use back button with warning or disable any insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180143/prevent-user-to-use-back-button-with-warning-or-disable-any-insert)

Answer (score 0):

Always validate on the server side. The client side validation is simply for responsiveness; the server side actually helps protect your server from attack and helps ensure data validity in your storage mechanism/script action.

On `page2.php`, setup the page to first validate (maybe with a `function validateData()`), and depending on the result, show an error and (optionally) a back button to `page1.php`. Otherwise (`else`), do whatever the script is supposed to do.

Example:

```
<?php

function validateMyForm(&$data) {
    $errors = array();

    $data['name'] = strip_tags($data['name']);
    if (!is_string($data['name']) || strlen($data['name']) < 3 || strlen($data['name']) >20) {
        $errors[] = 'Name field must be provided (3-20 characters)';
    }

    return $errors;
}

$errors = validateMyForm($_POST);

if (count($errors)) {
    echo "
<h1>Form Errors</h1>
<ul>
<li>
";
    echo implode('</li><li>',$errors);
    echo '
</li>
</ul>
<p><a href="javascript:history.back()">Go back</a></p>
';
} else {
    // do form stuff
}

?>
```

Comment: Yes, I kind of figured that I can do that.  But I want to give the user the opportunity to reenter the information on page1.php and also not lose any of the original info that he/she entered.  Validating on page2.php does not allow me to do this unless I pass the form values back to page1.php.

Comment: I believe that using `history.back()` can preserve the form fields (not sure about this). Alternatively, you could put the `page1.php` within the `page2.php` error result and repopulate.

Comment: @ColShrapnel - Gee, how did I guess? What is it now?

Answer (score 0):

> what if the action of my form is another .php file?

Easy. Just make it the form itself.

Comment: You're mischaracterizing what the OP is asking for.