# how to print error message in HTML/PHP?

Tags: php, syntax-error, isset

I am checking if the particular parameter is passed and if a folder exists for that parameter. ex

```
if ((! isset($_GET["name"])) or (! is_dir($_GET["name"]))) {

    print "----------------USER NOT FOUND-----------------" ;
}
```

and in my URL if have name=Erik and if that folder does not exist in that name, I want to print the Error message.
Also I would like to check if the parameter'name' is passed into URL using isset.
Somehow the above does not work and I am unable to figure out why.
Any input will help.

Thanks

Comment: Everything seems okay. Does it return an error? What happens instead of working as it should?

Comment: I always do `echo "User not found";` and use `||` for 'or'. None of them will make any difference, but you could try to see if something changes.

Comment: The latter will actually make a difference, I explained better in my answer.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180143/prevent-user-to-use-back-button-with-warning-or-disable-any-insert

Answer (score 0):

`or` has a different use. It's for whenever something you are trying to do does not work, then it executes the other bit. Typical **deprecated** example would be when you try to do some database interaction, you'd write back then `$STH = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users') or die();`. For your case, you should use the `||` operator instead, [as explained in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Besides, you are not checking if someone submitted something. This will never print anything if a form is submitted with nothing in it. Both errors fixed, your code should look something like this:

```
if (empty($_GET["name"]) || !is_dir($_GET["name"])) {
print "----------------USER NOT FOUND-----------------" ;
}
```

Because, if someone submits the form, the url will be `example.com/index.php?name=`, which makes `$_GET['name']` to be set while it's empty. I assume you want to say User not found in that situation.

Comment: But `or` works perfectly in this case. Plus, `OR` can be used as a substitue of `||` as long as you keep in mind precedence.