# An example of form validation inside php

Tags: php, mysql, validation, mysqli

The below show an example of implementing form validation inside php to detect empty field or unwanted character and alert the error message as output. I have no credit in this work, i barely compound them to suit my own site needs. This is just to share my code as I did found some difficulty to find one before. The answer below does provide a more advance solution which I failed to make it work thou, it's not their problem but due to my novice skill in php .

So I basically just show the basic step to help another novice like me before. The below code show a very basic php form validation and email to the specific email address when the user press submit.

```
<?php
   $me =$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']; 
 if ($_POST['mail']=='' && $me =="POST") { //remember in the input tag,set name as 'mail' and in form tag set action to " "; 

$name = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z]/','', $_POST['name']);//filter all letters only
$tel = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','', $_POST['tel']);//filter all number only
//$email$regex credit to Adam Khoury www.developphp.com
$email = $_POST['email'];
$regex = '/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/'; 

$comments = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $_POST['comments']); //allow alphanumeric only

$error_status = false;//set default error status as false

if (empty($email)){ //empty in the field, it should go through these codes, remember don't put any value in the input tag thou, or else it will detect it as the default value
$error_email='<h4>Please fill in your email</h4>';
$error_status = true; //error status toggle
} else
if (preg_match($regex, $email)) { //if this is to ensure the format of email correctly entered
   } else { 
     $error_email='<h4>This is an invalid email. Please try again.</h4>';
     $error_status = true;
} 


if (empty($name)){
$error_name= '<h4>Please Fill Your Name</h4>';
$error_status = true;
} 

if (empty($tel)){
$error_tel ='<h4>Please Fill Your Contact Number</h4>';
$error_status = true;
}

if (empty($comments)){
$error_comments ='<h4>Please give us comments</h4>';
$error_status = true;
}


if(!$error_status) {
$success='<h4>Thanks for your comments. We will reply to you shortly</h4>';
$to_address="someone@gmail.com";
$subject="Online Comments";

$message="Input from online comments box.\n\n";
$message .="Name: ".$name."\n";
$message .="Tel: ".$tel."\n";
$message .="Email: ".$email."\n";
$message .="Comments: ".$comments."\n";

mail($to_address, $subject, $message);
unset($name,$tel,$email,$comments);
}
}

?>
```

Comment: A rough (but useful) example http://stackoverflow.com/a/5180165/285587

Comment: }  else {
    // all field values should be escaped according to HTML standard
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
      $form[$key] = htmlspecialchars($val);
    }
} else {
  $form['name'] = $form['comments'] = '';  
}
include 'form.tpl.php';

Comment: what is the include 'form.tpl.php'; for?

Comment: For to show the HTML form yet keep it separated from the application code

Comment: i added your code and edited a bit on top of the <html> and it shows Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$err' (T_VARIABLE) is that the right place to implement it?

Comment: You need to learn basic PHP syntax to avoid such errors.

Comment: yea..i am total noob in this =.= any light for me?

Comment: i added <?php in front of the code and it say Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) ...not sure how to modified the code

Comment: put ALL HTML code into tpl file

Comment: still not working? any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is in your if statement

replace this:

```
if (empty($_POST['customer_name']) $err[] = "Username field is required";  
if (empty($_POST['tel_num']) $err[] = "Comments field is required";
```

with:

```
if (empty($_POST['customer_name'])) {
  $err[] = "Username field is required";
  }  
if (empty($_POST['tel_num'])) {
  $err[] = "Comments field is required";  
}
```

The problem was that you missed a `)` after the `)` that was standing.

So you had this:

```
empty($_POST['customer_name']) //notice 1 (
```

but it have to be this:

```
empty($_POST['customer_name'])) //notice 2 (
```

Also you use the shorttag (`<?`) for opening php but you better use `<?php` like you do in your other scripts

**edit**

In cart.php you should use this code:

```
<?php  
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {  
  $err = array();
  //performing all validations and raising corresponding errors
  if (empty($_POST['customer_name'])) {
  $err[] = "Username field is required";
  }  
  if (empty($_POST['tel_num'])) {
  $err[] = "Comments field is required";  
  }

  if (empty($err)) {  
    //if no errors - saving data and redirect
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit;
  }  else {
    // all field values should be escaped according to HTML standard
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
      $form[$key] = htmlspecialchars($val);
    }
  }
} else {
  $form['customer_name'] = 'm;
  $form['tel_num'] = '';  
}
include 'form.tpl.php';
?>
```

**EDIT2**
I checked again the code that is in your question. I could not find any problems. I did make some little changes

I think when you use this script it should be working:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    /* Created by Adam Khoury @ www.developphp.com */

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    // Connect to the MySQL database  
    include "storescripts/connect_to_mysqli.php";

    // Determine which page ID to use in our query below ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    if (!empty($_GET['pid'])) {
        $pageid = 1;
    } else {
        $pageid = preg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $_GET['pid']); // filter everything but numbers for security
    }

    // Query the body section for the proper page
    $sqlCommand = "SELECT pagebody FROM pages WHERE id='$pageid' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die(mysqli_error());
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $body = $row["pagebody"];
    }
    mysqli_free_result($query);
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Query the module data for display ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $sqlCommand = "SELECT modulebody FROM modules WHERE showing='1' AND name='footer' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die(mysqli_error());
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $footer = $row["modulebody"];
    }
    mysqli_free_result($query);
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Query the module data for display ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $sqlCommand = "SELECT modulebody FROM modules WHERE showing='1' AND name='custom1' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die(mysqli_error());
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $custom1 = $row["modulebody"];
    }
    mysqli_free_result($query);
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Build Main Navigation menu and gather page data here -----------------------------------------------------------------------------


    $sqlCommand = "SELECT id, linklabel FROM pages WHERE showing='1' ORDER BY id DESC";
    $query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die(mysqli_error());

    $menuDisplay = '';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $pid = $row["id"];
        $linklabel = $row["linklabel"];
        $menuDisplay .= '<a href="index.php?pid=' . $pid . '">' .
                $linklabel . '</a><br />';
    }
    mysqli_free_result($query);
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //mysqli_close($myConnection); 
    // This file is www.developphp.com curriculum material
    // Written by Adam Khoury January 01, 2011
    // http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=442E340A42191003
    // Script Error Reporting
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //       Section 1 (if user attempts to add something to the cart from the product page)
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
        $pid = $_POST['pid'];
        $wasFound = false;
        $i = 0;
        // If the cart session variable is not set or cart array is empty
        if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
            // RUN IF THE CART IS EMPTY OR NOT SET
            $_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(0 => array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
        } else {
            // RUN IF THE CART HAS AT LEAST ONE ITEM IN IT
            foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
                $i++;
                while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
                    if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $pid) {
                        // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
                        array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i - 1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => $each_item['quantity'] + 1)));
                        $wasFound = true;
                    } // close if condition
                } // close while loop
            } // close foreach loop
            if ($wasFound == false) {
                array_push($_SESSION["cart_array"], array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
            }
        }
        header("location: cart.php");
        exit();
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //       Section 2 (if user chooses to empty their shopping cart)
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (isset($_GET['cmd']) && $_GET['cmd'] === 'emptycart') {
        unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //       Section 3 (if user chooses to adjust item quantity)
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (isset($_POST['item_to_adjust']) && $_POST['item_to_adjust'] != "") {
        // execute some code
        $item_to_adjust = $_POST['item_to_adjust'];
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
        $quantity = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $quantity); // filter everything but numbers
        if ($quantity >= 100) {
            $quantity = 99;
        }
        if ($quantity < 1) {
            $quantity = 1;
        }
        if (empty($quantity)) {
            $quantity = 1;
        }
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
            $i++;
            while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
                if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $item_to_adjust) {
                    // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
                    array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i - 1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $item_to_adjust, "quantity" => $quantity)));
                } // close if condition
            } // close while loop
        } // close foreach loop
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //       Section 4 (if user wants to remove an item from cart)
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (isset($_POST['index_to_remove']) && $_POST['index_to_remove'] !== '') {
        // Access the array and run code to remove that array index
        $key_to_remove = $_POST['index_to_remove'];
        if (count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) <= 1) {
            unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
        } else {
            unset($_SESSION["cart_array"][$key_to_remove]);
            sort($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
        }
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //       Section 5  (render the cart for the user to view on the page)
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $cartOutput = "";
    $cartTotal = "";
    $pp_checkout_btn = '';
    $product_id_array = '';

    if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
        $cartOutput = "<h3 align='center'>Your shopping cart is empty</h3>";
    } else {
        // Start PayPal Checkout Button

        $pp_checkout_btn .= '<form action="http://chenlikpharmacy.freeserver.me/order_list.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cartOutput" value = "$cartOutput">';

        // Start the For Each loop
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
            $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
            $sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1";
            $sql = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                $product_name = $row["product_name"];
                $price = $row["price"];
                $details = $row["details"];
            }
            $pricetotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
            $cartTotal = $pricetotal + $cartTotal;
            setlocale(LC_MONETARY, "en_US");
            $pricetotal = money_format("%10.2n", $pricetotal);
    // Dynamic Checkout Btn Assembly

            $pp_checkout_btn .= '<input type="hidden" name="item_name[]" value="' . $product_name . '">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount[]" value="' . $price . '">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity[]" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '">  ';
            // Create the product array variable
            $product_id_array .= "$item_id-" . $each_item['quantity'] . ",";
            // Dynamic table row assembly
            $cartOutput .= "<tr>";
            $cartOutput .= '<td><a href="product.php?id=' . $item_id . '">' . $product_name . '</a><br /><img src="inventory_images/' . $item_id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="40" height="52" border="1" /></td>';
            $cartOutput .= '<td>' . $details . '</td>';
            $cartOutput .= '<td>RM' . $price . '</td>';
            $cartOutput .= '<td><form action="cart.php" method="post">
            <input name="quantity" type="text" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '" size="1" maxlength="2" />
            <input name="adjustBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="change" />
            <input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '" />
            </form></td>';
            //$cartOutput .= '<td>' . $each_item['quantity'] . '</td>';
            $cartOutput .= '<td>' . $pricetotal . '</td>';
            $cartOutput .= '<td><form action="cart.php" method="post"><input name="deleteBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="X" /><input name="index_to_remove" type="hidden" value="' . $i . '" /></form></td>';
            $cartOutput .= '</tr>';
            $i++;
        }
        setlocale(LC_MONETARY, "ms_MY");
        $cartTotal = money_format("%10.2n", $cartTotal);
        $cartTotal = "<div style='font-size:18px; margin-top:12px;' align='right'>Cart Total : " . $cartTotal . " MYR</div>";
        // Finish the Paypal Checkout Btn
        $pp_checkout_btn .= '<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="' . $product_id_array . '">
    Name: <input type="text" name="customer_name">
    <br/>
    Tel: <input type="text" name="tel_num">

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>';
    }

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $err = array();
        //performing all validations and raising corresponding errors
        if (empty($_POST['customer_name'])) {
            $err[] = "Username field is required";
        }
        if (empty($_POST['tel_num'])) {
            $err[] = "Comments field is required";
        }

        if (empty($err)) {
            //if no errors - saving data and redirect
            header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            exit;
        } else {
            // all field values should be escaped according to HTML standard
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
                $form[$key] = htmlspecialchars($val);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $form['customer_name'] = '';
        $form['tel_num'] = '';
    }
    include 'form.tpl.php';
    ?>  
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
        <head>
            <title>CHENLIK PHARMACY ONLINE CATALOGUE</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="css/images/favicon.ico" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
            <!--[if IE 6]>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/png-fix.js"></script>
            <![endif]-->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <!-- Header -->
            <div id="header" class="shell">
                <div id="logo">
                    <h1><a href="http://chenlikpharmacy.freeserver.me/index.php">Chenlik Pharmacy Sdn. Bhd.</a></h1><span><a href="http://chenlikpharmacy.freeserver.me">Serve with Care & Passion</a></span></div>

                <!-- Navigation -->
                <div id="navigation">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://chenlikpharmacy.freeserver.me/index.php" >Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://chenlikpharmacy.freeserver.me/product_list.php">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://chenlikpharmacy.freeserver.me/promotions.php">Promotions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://chenlikpharmacy.freeserver.me/profile.php">Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://chenlikpharmacy.freeserver.me/about_us.php" class="active">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://chenlikpharmacy.freeserver.me/contacts.php" >Contacts</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <!-- End Navigation -->

                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>

                <!-- Login-details -->

                <div id="login-details">

                    <p>Welcome, <a href="#" id="user">Guest</a> .</p>
                    <p><a href="http://chenlikpharmacy.freeserver.me/cart.php" class="cart" ><img src="css/images/cart-icon.png" alt="" /></a>Shopping Cart <a href="http://chenlikpharmacy.freeserver.me/cart.php" class="sum"> Cart Total</a></p>

                </div>

                <!-- End Login-details -->

            </div>
            <!-- End Header -->


            <!-- Main -->

            <div id="main" class="shell">


                <!-- Products -->
                <div id="main" class="products">            
                    <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="18%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Product</strong></td>
                            <td width="45%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Product Description</strong></td>
                            <td width="10%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Unit Price</strong></td>
                            <td width="9%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Quantity</strong></td>
                            <td width="9%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Total</strong></td>
                            <td width="9%" bgcolor="#C5DFFA"><strong>Remove</strong></td>
                        </tr>
    <?php echo $cartOutput; ?><br/>

        <!-- <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr> -->
                    </table>
    <?php echo $cartTotal; ?>
                    <br />
                    <br />
    <?php echo $pp_checkout_btn; ?>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <a href="cart.php?cmd=emptycart">Click Here to Empty Your Shopping Cart</a>

                    <!-- End Products -->


                    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>

                </div>



                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>

            </div>

            <!-- End Main -->

            <!-- Footer -->

            <div id="footer" class="shell">

                <div class="top">

                    <div class="cnt">

                        <div class="col about">

                            <h4>About Chenlik Pharmacy Sdn. Bhd.</h4>

    <?php echo $custom1; ?>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col store">

                            <h4>Store</h4>

    <?php echo $footer; ?>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col" id="newsletter">

                            <h4>Newsletter</h4>

                            <p>This function is not activate yet. </p>

                            <form action="" method="post">

                                <input type="text" class="field" value="Your Name" title="Your Name" />

                                <input type="text" class="field" value="Email" title="Email" />

                                <div class="form-buttons"><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-btn" />
                                </div>

                            </form>

                        </div>

                        <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>

                        <div class="copy">

                            <p>&copy;2013 <a href="http://chenlikpharmacy.freeserver.me">Chenlik Pharmacy Sdn. Bhd.</a>&nbspDesign by <a href="http://css-free-templates.com/">CSS-FREE-TEMPLATES.COM</a> &nbsp.Source code credit to: <a href="http://www.developphp.com">Adam Khoury</a>. Modified & Complied by: Philip Tiong</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Footer -->
        </body>
    </html>
```

To show the errors you will need to add this in the html where you want to display the errors:

```
<?php
if (!empty($err)) :
foreach ($err as $error) :
echo $error; 
endforeach;
endif;
```

Comment: tried but still no luck...i even not sure whether i should place the above code in new php block above html on my cart.php . as the form field is integrated inside the loop and echo out...i kinda lost

Comment: Do you get stil the error? Also the best wat is todo your Logic and after that the html.

Comment: yea still error, i implement that whole block of php as above. and in case i copy the whole block of html in a new file form.tpl.php although i have no idea how it works...and under my cart i didnt change a thing as no form is created in the under html....I echo it out the form etc in the php block..that's why I can't the logic to make this work..unless some magic code can be implemented inside the php block where i create the form above html...you understand me right? and i understand this is beyond my scope really..

Comment: i tried..i edited my post to show you exactly what my code is..it still show Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in /home/u382560552/public_html/cart.php on line 234

Comment: i pretty sure is the starting of the last block of php `code` <?php  
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {  
  $err = array(); etc...

Comment: @PhilipTiong I checked the code you have now, there is no error? If there is a error then maybe it comes from a other file that you include..

Comment: this error occur only when I put the last block of php in..if i remove that all works fine...the form.tpl.php file basically i just copy and paste the cart.php code starting from the doctype to the end ...i not sure how this validation work thou..thanks for your time Perry

Comment: and one weird thing i observe..with the beginning of last block of php if i write `code` <? php blah blah blah `code` it shows Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Â ' (T_STRING) in /home/u382560552/public_html/cart.php on line 233

if without space `code` <?php blah blah blah `code` it show the d 'if' (T_IF) in /home/u382560552/public_html/cart.php on line 234

Comment: About the error on line 233 it looks like your encoding of your file is different. Also see edit 2, I changed your code a little bit check if this works.

Comment: it submitted the data successfully but not prompting the message even thou I leave the name and tel_num field empty

Comment: I add now code to show the error. You should place that where you want to show the error on your page.

Comment: tried no luck..not sure the code detect the empty field actually work cause when I leave it empty and submit the order it still show the echo in my order_list.php (edited and include above) . If it works it should not direct to that place and echo out "order submitted succesffuly etc right?"

Answer (score 1):

You check if the form fields are posted first and valid in the e.g. cart.php like this for example:

```
if(is_numeric($_POST["quantity"]) && $_POST["quantity"]>0) {
 $each_item['quantity']=$_POST["quantity"];
}
```

Now you are checking that quantity is numeric and not zero.
You can do this for more fields and depending on the type you build your check like:

```
if(!empty($_POST["customer_name"])) {
 $customerName=$_POST["customer_name"];
}
```

For more advanced validation you can use regular expressions: [preg-match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: where should add the line?

Answer (score 0):

php can be used for server side validation, i.e., after you submit the form.
if you want to validate the entry during the form being filled, you need to use jquery. i am mentioning an example for both the ways.

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#registerationform" ).validate({
    rules: {
           fname:"required",
           lname:"required",
           age: {required: true,
                number: true,
                digits: true,

           },
           email:{ required:true,
                    email: true
           },
           pword:{required: true,
                    minlength: 5
           },
           uname: {required : true
           }

        },
   messages: {
        fname:"Please, enter your First name",
        lname:"Please, enter your Last name",
        age:{required :"Please, Enter your age",
             number: "Only numerals"
        },
        email: {required :"Please, Enter your Email ID",
                email :"Please, Enetr a valid Email ID"
        },
        pword:{required:"Please, Enter your password",
                minlength:"Minimum 5 character required"
        },
        uname:"Please, Enter your UserName"


        }

    });
});
</script>


<form name="registerationform" id="registerationform" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="signup">
    <div class="editProfileCont">
            <div class="formFieldRow">
             <div class="fields">

    First Name<sup><font color="#FF0000">*</sup></font>: <input type="text" name="fname"  maxlength="30" id="fname" class="required" minlength="1" value="<?php if(isset($_POST[fname])){ echo $_POST[fname];}?>"></div></div><br><br>
     <div class="formFieldRow">
         <div class="fields">
    Last Name<sup><font color="#FF0000">*</sup></font>: <input type="text" name="lname"  maxlength="30" id="lname" class="required" minlength="1" value="<?php if(isset($_POST[lname])){ echo $_POST[lname];}?>"></div></div> <br><br>
     <div class="formFieldRow">
         <div class="fields">
    Age<sup><font color="#FF0000">*</sup></font>:       <input type="text" name="age" maxlength="2" id="age" class="required" minlength="1" value="<?php if(isset($_POST[age])){ echo $_POST[age];}?>"></div></div><br>
    <b><?php echo $errorEmail?><br></b>
     <div class="formFieldRow">
         <div class="fields">
    E-Mail Id<sup><font color="#FF0000">*</sup></font>: <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="40" id="email" class="required email" minlength="1" value="<?php if(isset($_POST[email])){ echo $_POST[email];}?>"></div></div><br>
    <b><?php echo $errorUname?><br></b>
    <div id="disp"></div>
     <div class="formFieldRow">
         <div class="fields">
    User Name<sup><font color="#FF0000">*</sup></font>: <input type="text" name="uname"  maxlength="10" id="uname" class="required" minlength="1" value="<?php if(isset($_POST[uname])){ echo $_POST[uname];}?>"></div></div> <br><br>
     <div class="formFieldRow">
         <div class="fields">
    Password<sup><font color="#FF0000">*</sup></font>:  <input type="password" name="pword" id="pword" class="required" minlength="5"></div></div><br><br><br>
```

this was jquery validation, on the same page as your form.
On the action page of form you perform php validation, which is pretty simple.

```
<?php
if(isset($_post['uname'])){
$uname = $_post['uname'];
$sql="INSERT INTO persons ( UserName )Values('$_POST[uname]')";
}else echo "please enter username/empty fields not allowed";
?>
```

Comment: i have edited and include the php that parse the data submited from cart.php..may i know where should i insert the line for your second option? i just need a simple way